# Can somebody explain what is meant by code source tree

Tags: 20.04, deb, development

I am trying to build a deb package from source code.
when I run:

```
debuild -b -uc -us
```

From the source code directory I get:

```
debuild: fatal error at line 679:
cannot find readable debian/changelog anywhere!
Are you in the source code tree?
```

Also there is this:

```
trey@focal:~/freac-1.1.3$ dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc -us
dpkg-buildpackage: error: cannot open file debian/changelog: No such file or directory
```

I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: You have an incomplete build configuration. Debian packages have a number of expectations in order to build in a consistent fashion. The walk-through [on this site](https://blog.packagecloud.io/debian/debuild/packaging/2015/06/08/buildling-deb-packages-with-debuild/) should give you what you need to successfully build your .deb 

Comment: The application [is available](https://www.freac.org/downloads-mainmenu-33) in all formats including Snap, Flatpak and AppImage. This application was [never released](https://repology.org/project/freac/versions) for Debian. So you have to create the `debian` folder by yourself. Anyway why do you think you need to compile it?

Comment: I have added the comment to related issue https://github.com/enzo1982/freac/issues/8 .

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIAL ANSWER**

FWIW, with respect to the

```
debuild: fatal error at line 679:
cannot find readable debian/changelog anywhere!
Are you in the source code tree?
```

squawk, I've found that, in many cases, installing the **fakeroot** package prevents said squawk from occurring...